# Wifi, Ethernet, Graphics Drivers, file system are all buggy. Are these issues related?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, wifi, nvidia, ethernet

**System Specs**: i7-12700k, RTX 3060, 80 (2X32, 2X8) GB DDR4-3200 RAM, 1 TB M2 NVME SSD

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, kernel version 5.2.21-050221-generic

**Context**:
My Motherboard doesn't have WiFi, so I use TP-Link Archer T9UH USB WiFi adapter for WiFi. Unfortunaly, 5.2.21 is the latest kernel version supported by the open source driver for the WiFi adapter. I had installed the 510.60 version of the Nvidia Driver a few months ago. I did not see any issues for a few months. Yesterday, I noticed that the Nvidia Driver is not working.

When I entered: `nvidia-smi` in the terminal, I got this error:

`Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch`

I then tried to reinstall the Nvidia Driver 515.76, it broke and when I rebooted, I got a blank screen. Then I tried again, The installation seemed sucessful and when I rebooted, both my Wifi and the ethernet drivers were broken? Then I noticed that the *Files* was showing *Filesystem root* and *efi* as mounted drives, and the GUI was very buggy and slow. It froze and took 10 minutes to move small files when using the GUI.

I am in a but of a pickle. I don't even know where to start. How do I even diagnose the problems here?

I will add any command output in a Edit if needed.

**EDIT**:

I downloaded the Nvidia Driver 520.56.06 as mentioned by Artem, directly form the Nvidia website , and Installed it.

But Immediately after the installation, My screen went completely black except for a underscore cursor in top left side of the screen.

**EDIT_1**:

After force Rebooting, The Nvidia Drivers seem to be working. But, the WiFi and ethernet problems are persisting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the Issue. All these problems occuring together is not a coincidence. I think the kernel version I was using, 5.2.21,  was simply too old.

I downloaded the 5.4.x kernel, installed it and booted into it.

This was where I found the files: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

You would need 4 `.deb` packages with the correct cpu architecture (`amd64` for Intel/AMD):

- `linux_headers-5.4.x-xxx_all.deb`
- `linux_headers-5.4.x-xxx-generic/lowlatency_xxx.deb`
- `linux_modules-5.4.x-xxx-generic/lowlatency_xxx.deb`
- `linux-image-unsigned-5.4.x-xxx-generic/lowlatency_xxx.deb`

download these manually if you have to and put all of these packages in a signle folder on the target system.

Then install the kernel packages by running the command:
`sudo dpkg -i *.deb`

Reboot and while rebooting, choose the correct kernel version.

check this by the following command:
`uname -r`

Answer (score 0):

Driver 515.76 is [known](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/bug-report-black-x11-screen-and-partial-lockup-when-upgraded-to-515-76-and-dual-rtx3060/228912) to be [incompatible](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/515-76-nvidia-drivers/229132) with some GeForce 30 series cards. Please use [520.56.06](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/193764/en-us) instead. Unfortunately I've no idea how to install it properly in Ubuntu. You could install NVIDIA's package directly but normally it's *not* recommended.

Please fix the display driver first, then create a new question for other issues. Let's not lump everything together.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a Linux Noob and all these issues came after I tried to reinstall the Nvidia Driver. Will Update

Comment: Immediately after installing this driver, my screen went completely black

Comment: Have you tried rebooting? Please try 515.65.01 as a last remedy https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/linux-amd64-display-archive/

Comment: 520.56.06 Driver is working after rebooting. Although the other problems are still there. nvidia-smi is working

Comment: Great, as for other issues, please create separate new questions for each of them.